# Set checked boxes for a checkBox-list dialog

Tags: android, dialog, checkbox, checkboxlist

I've got a dialog which shows a list of checkBoxes. I'd like to set different boxes checked each time the dialog is showed. But that only works the first time.. I want it work every time the dialog is showed!  It would be great if anyone can help...

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

            case CHECKBOX_LIST_DIALOG:

                final CharSequence[] weeks = new CharSequence[53];

                for (int i=0; i<=52; i++) {
                    weeks[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
                }

                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(
                        R.string.txt_week_checkbox_list).setMultiChoiceItems(
                        weeks, getCheckedBoxes(),
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                                checked[whichButton] = isChecked;
                            }
                        }).setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_weeks);
                                editText.setText(generateString());
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        }).create();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed dialogs created via `onCreateDialog()` are cached. You will need to override `onPrepareDialog()`, so you get control when the dialog is next shown. You are passed the `Dialog` object. Cast that to an `AlertDialog`, call `getListView()`, and use `setItemChecked()` to toggle each checkbox on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Great! That did it, thanks!! That was exactly what I was looking for :-)
Here's what I did to make it work like you explained:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
    boolean[] checked = myDialog.getCheckedBoxes();
    for (int i=0; i<checked.length; i++)
        if (checked[i])
            lv.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```